# How to print string using pl/sql without appending the new line character at end

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

If I use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()` method, it always appends a new line character at end.

But what if I want to print lets say Fibonacci series in same line.

I know the logic of fibonacci...

I just want to know which method would I use to put whole output in same line.

I am using PL/SQL

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT` instead of `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`

Answer (score 5):

The entry point for all the doc of version 11gR2 is [All Books for Oracle Database Online Documentation Library 11g Release 2 (11.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/nav/portal_booklist.htm).

For other Oracle database versions you might want to start your exploration from [Database Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/en/database/). Since version 12.1 the URLs are easier : http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/nav/portal_booklist.htm for 12.1 and http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/nav/portal_booklist.htm for 12.2.

You might want to check [PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/toc.htm) for that kind of question. In particular the [Summary of DBMS_OUTPUT Subprograms](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_output.htm#ARPLS67313). The doc is really handy as a reference when you have questions about the PL/SQL API.

Comment: Also note from the documentation, "The maximum line size is 32767 bytes."

Comment: The links are broken.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have updated the links and added the general entry point to the documentation for 11gR2.